# Dongle not working in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, dongle

My dongle stopped working and when I went to the flagship store where I bought it, they said it's because I'm using windows 8 in my laptop.  Most dongles stop working with OS because of some updates. He told me to switch to a different OS - like W7 - to solve the problem.

Dongle - prolink PHS600

It's hard to believe, is this really true? If this is really true, then isn't there a better solution than switching between OSes?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the drivers of your Windows 8: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/usb-modem/prolink/phs600/sub-models/

> Compatibility:    Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8

Comment: Thanks but in the above link, it has to be purchased.